# Split SQL string with specific string instead of separator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I have table that looks like:

```
|ID  | String
|546 | 1,2,1,5,7,8
|486 | 2,4,8,1,5,1
|465 | 18,11,20,1,4,18,11
|484 | 11,10,11,12,50,11
```

I want to split the string to this:

```
|ID  | String
|546 | 1,2
|546 | 1,5
|486 | 1,5,1
|486 | 1
|465 | 1,4
```

My goal is to show ID and all the strings starting with 1 with just the next number after them.

I filtered all rows without `'%1,%'` and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Can you also post what you have tried so that we can stat from there.

Comment: Your data model is broken. Normalize the data and the problem goes away.

Comment: Are you sure about `486 | 1,5,1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try to use a JSON-based approach. You need to transform the data into a valid JSON array and parse the JSON array with `OPENJSON()`. Note that `STRING_SPLIT()` is not an option here, because as is mentioned in the documentation, *the output rows might be in any order and the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID int,
   [String] varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (ID, [String])
VALUES   
   (546, '1,2,1,5,7,8'),
   (486, '2,4,8,1,5,1'),
   (465, '18,11,20,1,4,18,11'),
   (484, '11,10,11,12,50,11')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   ID,
   CONCAT(FirstValue, ',', SecondValue) AS [String]
FROM (   
   SELECT 
      d.ID, 
      j.[value] As FirstValue, 
      LEAD(j.[value]) OVER (PARTITION BY d.ID ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j.[key])) AS SecondValue
   FROM Data d
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', d.[String], ']')) j
) t
WHERE t.FirstValue = '1'
```

Result:

```
----------
ID  String
----------
465 1,4
486 1,5
486 1,
546 1,2
546 1,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
SELECT ID, S.value
FROM   Data
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(',' + String, ',1,', '#1,'), '#') AS S
WHERE  value LIKE '1,%'
```

?